# cannot access app.user variable in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I cannot access app.user variable in the main. But, I can access the variable in the admin part. I tried to google it and found that it is due to firewall problem. But, I cannot figure it out where the problem is.

**Security.yml**

**Firewall**

```
firewalls:
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            provider: admin_security
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /admin
                check_path:  /admin/login_check
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
                failure_path: /admin

            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin

        company_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: company_security
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                default_target_path: /main/dashboard
                failure_path: /

            logout:
                path:   /main/logout
                target: /login
```

**Updated**

**Login Check Script**

```
if($encoder->isPasswordValid($client->getPassword(), $password, $client->getSalt()))
                    {
                        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($username,$password, 'company_area', $client->getRoles());
                        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
                        $this->get('session')->set('_security_company_area',serialize($token));

                        //now dispatch the login event

                        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
                        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
                        //Now you can redirect where ever you need and the user will be logged in
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateURL('main_dashboard'));
                    }
```

Comment: "I cannot access app.user variable in the main" - what error do you get?

Comment: I get blank value for app.user
Yes, I am logged in. I have used my own authentication method for admin.

Comment: try to add `context` option with the same value to both of your firewalls.

Comment: I didn't get you...Can you elaborate or give some code snippet

Comment: [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context)